# java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I am getting a runtime exception when I am calling `NavDrawerActivity` from `LoginScreen` activity.

Error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not
>   resumed:
>   {com.example.owner.loginapp/com.example.owner.loginapp.NavDrawerActivity}

How to fix this error?

Here is my `loginScreen` code

```
 package com.example.owner.loginapp;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;

 public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView image;
    ImageView user_img;
    ImageView pass_img;
    Button log_in;
    Button reg;
    EditText editText_Username;
    EditText editText_Pass;
    UserSessionManager session;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Reg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.smile);

        user_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_img);
        user_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_img);

        pass_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pass_img);
        pass_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pass);

        log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Reg);

        editText_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_UserName);
        editText_Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        image.setImageBitmap(icon);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username = editText_Username.getText().toString();
                String password = editText_Pass.getText().toString();

                if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    String uName = null;
                    String uPassword = null;

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("Name")) {
                        uName = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "");

                    }
                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("Password")) {
                        uPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("Password", "");

                    }
                    if (username.equals(uName) && password.equals(uPassword)) {

                        session.createUserLoginSession(uName, uPassword);

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavDrawerActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username/Password is incorrect",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter username and password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.register);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Reg.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the exact quote of your full error code as it often contains more useful information besides the name of the error.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.owner.loginapp/com.example.owner.loginapp.NavDrawerActivity}

Comment: this is the exception showing

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavDrawerActivity.class); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  modify the last line also to addflags and verify

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tried to instantiate a `Reg` `Activity` class that I designed and everything worked fine. It is possible that you are doing something wrong in the 1onResume`or`onCreate` of Reg class.

Post that class too for more information.